# std::for_each and unordered_map value modification with parallel execution policy

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, c++17, thread-safety

Does this usage of parallel for_each is ok with unordered_map:

```
void test() 
{
   std::vector<double> vec;
   constexpr auto N = 1000000;
   for(auto i=0;i<N;i++) // this is just for the example purpose
       vec.push_back(i*1.0);
   auto my_map = std::unordered_map<double,double>();

   for(const auto d: vec)
       my_map.try_emplace(d,d); // I prefill the map with some elements

   // Here i use par_unseq but just modify the value not the key, so just individual elements of the map
   std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,vec.cbegin(),vec.cend(),[&](double d) { return my_map.at(d)=d+1.0;});

   auto total=0.0;
   for(const auto [key,value]: my_map)
       total+=value;
   std::cout << total << std::endl;
}
```

I first fill the unordered_map with empty elements and then just modify each individual elements. All my tests are successful but I dont know if its just luck or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t):

> When using parallel execution policy, it is the programmer's responsibility to avoid data races and deadlocks

So, no (direct) help from the Standard Library there.

However, as you yourself point put, this line:

`my_map.at(d)=d+1.0;`

is only *reading* the map.  The only thing it's writing to is the *elements* (by which I mean values) in the map, and since each parallel path of execution will be writing to a *different* element, this should be OK.

Sidenote: your lambda doesn't need to return anything.

Comment: Yes agree for the lambda return statement. So modifying the value (as in the key,value pair) is not considered as modifying an element of the map. What about moving it ? like my_map.at(d) = std::move(c) should be allowed then ?

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'element' (I meant 'value', I guess), but yes, modifying the values in the map from within your lambda is fine.  And moving from something is no exception (unless there's some race condition on the object you're moving from).

Comment: ... It's fine because the data structures that make up the map itself are not changed in any way by updating a value stored in the map.